# i want to number my rows in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, row

im using core data i have an entity called questions whenever i add my question to my table i want them to display the number of the question (kind of like auto increment thing)
can anyone pls help me out
thanks

here is my code if its relevant

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
  }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
     return [self.questionArray count];
  }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];


// Configure the cell...

questionObject = [self.questionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = questionObject.questionDescription;


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (nil == cell) {
      cell = ...; //create a cell instance if it wasn't found in reusable cache
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    questionObject = [self.questionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *cellText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d. %@", indexPath.row+1, questionObject.questionDescription];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;


    return cell;
}
```